# how to select empty input in each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through a form of inputs and pushing all the input values to an array for some manipulation later in my code. On the other hand, when I loop through each input, I would like to check if the selected input is empty, if its empty I want to set its value to "-". Here is what I have so far--

When I run and test this code, the correct value is not outputted. What am I missing?

```
$('.NewTeam').eq(i).find('tr').each(function(event) { 

  //each row is one player
  var Player = []; //A new array for every player

  TeamInfo = TeamInfo + "\n Player " + counter + "\n";

  $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).value == "") {
      $(this).val("--");
      TeamInfo = TeamInfo + this.value + "  , " + " ";
      Player.push(this.value);
    }
    TeamInfo = TeamInfo + this.value + "  , " + " ";
    Player.push(this.value);
  });

  counter++;
  TeamArray.push(Player);

});
```

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: In $('.NewTeam').eq(i) where is i coming from?

Comment: @SureshKoya eq(i) is coming from a for loop. I will edit the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up uses of value. `$(this).value` is not a valid property. jQuery has a method `val()` that returns `this.value`. So you need to call `$(this).val()` consistently. Below I have removed the `if` statement and instantiated a tmp variable called `value`. The way I assign it is `var value = $(this).val() || "--";` What this is saying is make value equal to the value of this node, unless it is falsey, then set it to `"--"`. I also removed some unnecessary concatenation in your strings.

```
  $('.NewTeam').eq(i).find('tr').each(function (event) {   //each row is one player
        var Player = []; //A new array for every player
        TeamInfo = TeamInfo +"\n Player " + counter + "\n";

        $(this).find(":input").each(function(){

          var value = $(this).val() || "--";

          TeamInfo = TeamInfo + value + "  ,  ";
          Player.push(this.value);
        });
        counter++;
        TeamArray.push(Player);
  });
```

Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Awesome! I've just started with web app development. Always looking for more precise solutions with jQuery. Thank you!

Comment: Since you just started I feel I should point out a couple of things. First, some people might call the `||` or syntax a bit of a hack. It is used quite often but some people have different preferences. If you want you can use a ternary operator to do the same thing. `var value = $(this).val() ? $(this).val()  : "--";`. Second, this checks for 'falsey' and 'truthy' values. As you refine this codes you might want to improve it by checking if `value.length === 0` or even better, check if `$.trim(value).length === 0` to eliminate white space. I would google truthy/falsy in JS and ternary

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

#### 1. $(this).value

You should either write `this.value` or `$(this).val()`, but not `$(this).value`.

So this

```
       if ($(this).value == ""){
```

should become:

```
       if ($(this).val() === ""){
```

#### 2. Duplicated code

You are doing this both inside the `if` block as outside of it:

```
       TeamInfo = TeamInfo + this.value + "  , " + " ";
       Player.push(this.value);
```

So if the `if` condition is true, it will happen twice. So better not do it inside the `if` block.

#### And...

You increment a counter at the time you push an element to the `TeamArray` array. If you want the counter to count the number of elements in an array, you can save yourself a line (and variable), because that is already available in `TeamArray.length`.

Comment: Terrible mistake. Thanks for catching that, works fine now.